# Printar 2 strings entrelaçadas

Tags: python, string, loop

Como eu printo 2 strings entrelaçadas(não sei se é assim que se chama.)?
Por exemplo:

```
string1='aovces'
string2='m o'
```

para que no print saia
"amo voces"
no caso, intercalando cada elemento de cada string, incluindo o espaço.

Answer (score 3):

Basta combinar as funções [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) e [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), ambas do módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

string1='aovces'
string2='m o'

interpolation = zip_longest(string1, string2, fillvalue='')

print(''.join(chain(*interpolation)))  # amo voces
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Svsu6U) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/StiffWiseReptile)</sup>

A função `zip_longest` irá retornar um gerador que itera sobre uma lista semelhante a:

```
[('a', 'm'), ('o', ' '), ('v', 'o'), ('c', ''), ('e', ''), ('s', '')]
```

Ou seja, cria pares com uma letra de cada *string* e, quando não houver mais caracteres em uma das *strings*, preenche com o valor definido por `fillvalue=''`. Ao fazer `*interpolation` como parâmetro de `chain`, todas as tuplas são passadas como parâmetros posicionais, o equivalente a:

```
chain(interpolation[0], interpolation[1], interpolation[2], interpolation[3], interpolation[4], interpolation[5])
```

A função `chain`, por sua vez, retorna um gerador que iterará sobre todas as tuplas, uma por vez, enquanto houverem valores. Seria o equivalente à lista:

```
['a', 'm', 'o', ' ', 'v', 'o', 'c', '', 'e', '', 's', '']
```

Assim, ao final, geramos a *string* com o método `join`.

> Esta solução funcionará para qualquer quantidade de *strings*, independente do tamanho de cada uma.

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução simples:

```
def entrelacar(string1=None, string2=None):
    s = list(string1)
    s2 = list(string2)
    resp = ''
    while s or s2:
        if s:
            resp += s.pop(0)
        if s2:
            resp += s2.pop(0)
    return resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print( entrelacar(string1='aovces', string2='m o'))
```

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss sim, vc tem razao. Editei o código agora.